# JQuery ignoring form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#generate").click(function() {
        var texts = [];
        alert();
        $("form label").each(function() {
            var oLabel = $(this);
            var oInput = oLabel.next();
            texts.push(oLabel.text() + " " + oInput.val());
        });
        texts[0] += texts[1];
        texts[2] += texts[3];
        for(i=3;i<texts.length;i++)
            texts[i-1] = texts[i];
        texts[texts.length-1] = null;
        $("#cont").html(texts.join("<br />"));
    });
});
```

What it do is it reads form elements then types them as regular text (there is a purpose for this).

And this is how my form looks like ...

```
<div id="cont" style="float:right; width:75%; height:auto">
    <form onSubmit="return generate();">
      <label class="itemLabel" for="name">Name : </label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="itemInput" value="<? echo $queryB[1]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />

        <label>@ Some Text</label><br />
        <label for="priPhone" class="itemLabel">Customer Telephone Number : </label>Phone#
        <input name="priPhone" type="text" class="itemInput" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $queryB[2]; ?>" />

        <label for="secPhone"> // Mobile#</label>
        <input name="secPhone" type="text" class="itemInput" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $queryB[3]; ?>" /><br />
        <label class="itemLabel" for="email">Customer Email Address : </label>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="itemInput" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $queryB[4]; ?>" /><br />

        <label>***************</label><br />
        <label>Best Regards,</label><br />
        <input name="another_field" type="text" /><br />
        <label>last thing</label><br />
        <button type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

now, when I click the button "Generate", everything goes well except that it ignores "another_field" and doesn't get its value

Anyone got an idea to solve this? (Note: This piece of code will be running on around 25 forms so I need to have it working.)

**UPDATE:**

*Sample output:*

```
Name : username @ Some Text
Customer Telephone Number :  90237590 // 3298579
Customer Email Address : email@host.com
***************
Best Regards,
last_field
last thing
```

**Workaround**

Since I'm having all the forms have the same ending, I've been able to get to this code:

```
texts[0] += " " + texts[1];
texts[1] = texts[2] + " " + texts[3];
for(i=4;i<texts.length;i++)
    texts[i-2] = texts[i];
texts[texts.length-2] = texts[texts.length-3];
texts[texts.length-3] = $("#agent").val() ;
texts[texts.length-1] = null;
```

It solved the problem, but I'm looking for a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#generate").click(function() {
        var texts = [];
        $("form").children().each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            if (el.prop('tagName') == "LABEL") texts.push(el.text());
            if (el.prop('tagName') == "INPUT") texts.push(el.val());
            if (el.prop('tagName') == "BR") texts.push("<br />");
        });
        $("#cont").html(texts.join(""));
    });
});
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5AD4/6/

Comment: But the problem that it has to be that way, so is it possible to get the value of "another_field" and put it in the array in the location it should be? I mean shift the array by one.

Comment: I need the output to be the same as the form.

Comment: And what part of my answer is preventing that?

Comment: your answer provided "undefined" in the output in multiple locations!!

Comment: ok, this kinda worked, EXCEPT that it merges the textbox with the label before it, and each SHOULD be in a separate line.

Can this be done? or should I be looking for another way like getting the value of the field and then inserting it in its position  in the array?

Comment: At this point I think it would helpful to state what your requirements are. So far you have only discussed implementation, and I really have no idea what you are trying to do. Providing some sample output would help.

Comment: sample output provided in question.

Comment: Workaround posted, but still looking for a better way to solve this.

Comment: still the same, I think I'll be working with the workaround I came to. But your answer helped :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "still the same" - my output matches your sample output as far as I can tell. Except for the extra "Mobile#" text, which could easily be removed by putting it inside another tag type.

Answer (score 3):

Your <br/> tag is the next tag after the label before "another_field". You should probably make your next call something like:

```
var oInput = oLabel.next('input');
```

Comment: But the problem that it has to be that way, so is it possible to get the value of "another_field" and put it in the array in the location it should be? I mean shift the array by one.

Comment: I need the output to be the same as the form.

Comment: Are you saying you can't alter your jquery code for some reason?

Comment: No, I can alter the JQuery, but when using your method, I get "undefined" in various places in the output.